# input field placeholder attribute ie7+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, coffeescript, placeholder, browser-detection

I am currently using the following library:

http://widgetulous.com/placeholderjs/

And using the following code to detect necessity of use/and to apply it to the fields requiring it:

```
 if navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!= -1 or navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident")!= -1
    $ ->
       Placeholder.init()
       numPlaceHolders = $('input[placeholder]').length
       window.setInterval(=>
          if ($('input[placeholder]').length != numPlaceHolders)
             numPlaceHolders = $('input[placeholder]').length
             Placeholder.init()
      , 1000)
```

The reason to have the Interval is that elements are dynamically generated at run time (I use Angular JS). Unfortunately, ie support is a must, and the placeholder attributes are unsupported...

So I have to questions:

1) How can I force Placeholder.init() to be applied to all new input fields with the placeholder attribute? Is there any way to avoid a continual looping interval? I am aware of DomChange events (various), but as far as I know they are a) deprecated and b) unsupported in ie?

2) Is there a better way to check browser compatability then explicitly asking for ie as I'm doing?

Comment: Doesn't Placeholder.js already detect UA for you? All this is much easier with jQuery. Is that an option?

Comment: jquery is a perfectly acceptable option, in fact, I believe I do use some jquery in my code snippet above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolved the first issue (direct check for ie rather then compatability):

Replacing:

```
 if navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!= -1 or navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident")!= -1
```

with

```
 if typeof(document.createElement('input').placeholder) == "undefined"
```

Still don't know if there's a better way to solve this issue then timeouts really